# How to find out if image has black borders?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, image-viewers

On Ubuntu 22.04, I'm trying to find a solution for finding out if an image has a black border around it. On Windows, I used to use MS Office Picture Manager. When an image is opened up in Picture Manager, it happens to have a creamy background with the entire image in the foreground:
[image]

But when an image is opened on Ubuntu, either with Image Viewer or with Shotwell, it has a **black** background, with the image in foreground so like this:
[image]

This makes it impossible to tell if the image has black borders that I may want to crop out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tried changing the "Background Color" in the preferences of the image viewer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Preferences" of Image Viewer, there is an option to change the background to a different color. Shotwell does not have an option to specifically change the image background. It follows the system theme. Here, if you disable "Use dark theme" in the preferences,you will see the pictures on a light gray background.

Comment: Just tried it and it does solve 50% of my problem. Could not find any such preferences in Shotwell, only Image Viewer, am I missing something?

Comment: @vanadlum thanks for the updated answer, appreciate your effort. I am gonna use this until i find a cropping software with different background. (Have GIMP installed so probably gonna try using that first).